# Scala Play 2.4 Filters (Logging, CORS) not working on Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0, cors, servlet-filters

I have a Scala Play (2.4) REST API that works fine locally. When I deployed it to Heroku, I ran into the CORS problem as I am calling it from a separate web application.

I resolved the issue by adding CORS filter based on documentation and I don't get the CORS error when running locally. But when deployed to Heroku, I still get the standard CORS error.

To isolate the problem, I added a simple logging filter to my application, which again works fine locally. But even this logging filter does not work on Heroku.

This made me think that probably my filters are not getting invoked when deployed to Heroku.

I am not sure how else to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have separate configuration for dev and production?

Comment: No I am only using the default application.conf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems odd as Heroku is really only running the output of

`% sbt stage`

Do you filters work if you create the `stage` build and then run whatever you have in `Procfile` (e.g:

`% target/universal/stage/bin/myappname -Dhttp.port=$PORT`

?

### A working setup:

I have several Play 2.4 apps running in Heroku with working filters, here's an example of what I have for the **Play 2.4.6** app in front of me right now:

#### In `build.sbt`

Ensure the `filters` dependency is specified:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws,
  cache,
  filters,
  ...
)
```

#### In `application.conf`

Configure the CORS Module:

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSModule"
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = null,      # This means "all"
  allowedHttpMethods = null   # This means "all"
  exposedHeaders = ["Authorization", "Content-Length", "Content-Type", "Content-disposition"],
  preflightMaxAge = 14 days
}
```

#### In `Filters.scala`

(which resides in the root of the `app` directory):

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.http.HttpFilters
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter

class Filters @Inject() (corsFilter: CORSFilter) extends HttpFilters {
  def filters = Seq(corsFilter)
}
```

If you've got everything configured like that and it's *still* not working, are you *sure* your deployments to Heroku are actually completing successfully? Check the logs ( `% heroku logs --tail` )

Comment: I compared my code to this, and am doing things exactly the same way. Accepting this as the answer as this is the right way. My issue got resolved by upgrading to Play 2.5